# Jekyll goes crazy with vim foldinig bracktes {{{ }}}

Tags: vim, markdown, jekyll, folding

Is it possible to use vim folding with jekyll?

Get the following error:

```
Liquid Exception: Variable '{{' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/
```

Tried // and /* */ for commenting out the line with the bracktes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vim *fold markers* for marker-based folding usually must be put into comments, to avoid interfering with the script's syntax.

You can also change the used markers, either for the *filetype* (`:set filetype?` tells you this), in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`, or for individual files via *modelines*, directly in the file (again commented out), like this:

```
vim: set foldmethod=marker foldmarker=[[[,]]]:
```

Answer (score 1):

You're colliding with Liquid variable tag `{{ myvar }}`.

Try to use Liquid comments :

```
{% comment %}
{{{ }}}
{% endcomment %}
```

Comment: That didn't worked. @ingo-karket hat a solution for this. Thanks anyway!